# Cannot install Visual Studio Professional and Community on Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8.1

I have a problem installing VS Professional 2012 and VS Community 2013 on Windows 8.1. The installation app crashes right after I open it.

Following [installation tips](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60f71a54-506e-4c70-be98-e993ce6d1ddf/visual-studio-installation-tips?forum=vssetup) I disabled anti-virus and firewall software and I installed all the available Windows updates, but nothing has changed.

Furthermore, I disabled .NET 3.5 and enabled all features for .NET 4.5 following [these tips](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/60f71a54-506e-4c70-be98-e993ce6d1ddf/visual-studio-installation-tips?forum=vssetup). Also, I downloaded and installed .NET 4.5.2 and DirectX, but it didn't help either.

Do you have any advice of what to do next?

Comment: capture a dump (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the crashing setup app. Open it in windbg, run **!analyze -v** and post the output.

Comment: I have a bunch of log files and I tried to install WinDBG with the installation app from the Microsoft website. But it occured that I have the same problem while opening this setup app as well.

Comment: share the logs (OneDrive, Dropbox), maybe they are helpful.

Comment: Hi, sorry it took so long, these are all the logs I found:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ew7g1r6tnl8t6vh/dumps.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, according to the dump, the setup crashes because of the Intel HD graphic driver:

```
EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 00000008
   Parameter[1]: 00000000
Attempt to execute non-executable address 00000000

PROCESS_NAME:  vs_professional.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - Die Anweisung in 0x%08lx verweist auf Speicher 0x%08lx. Der Vorgang %s konnte nicht im Speicher durchgef hrt werden.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  00000000

WRITE_ADDRESS:  00000000 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
igdumdim32!OpenAdapter+c5e27
071b6e27 8bd0            mov     edx,eax

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+0
00000000 ??              ???

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  vs_professional.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.10075.9 x86fre

MANAGED_CODE: 1

MANAGED_ENGINE_MODULE:  clr

MANAGED_ANALYSIS_PROVIDER:  SOS

BUGCHECK_STR:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_SEHOP_NULL

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  SOFTWARE_NX_FAULT_SEHOP_NULL

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 071b6e27 to 00000000

STACK_TEXT:  
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
0x0
igdumdim32!OpenAdapter+0xc5e27
igdumdim32!OpenAdapter+0xce83a
igdumdim32!OpenAdapter+0xa8661
d3d9!CD3DDDIDX10::TexBlt+0x94
d3d9!CD3DBase::TexBlt+0x5a
d3d9!CMipMap::UpdateDirtyPortion+0xa5
d3d9!CResourceManager::UpdateVideoInternal+0x12b
d3d9!CD3DBase::UpdateTextures+0x652
d3d9!CD3DBase::DrawPrimitive+0x21d
wpfgfx_v0400!CD3DDeviceLevel1::DrawPrimitiveUP+0x3ae
wpfgfx_v0400!CD3DDeviceLevel1::FlushBufferFan+0x27
wpfgfx_v0400!CD3DDeviceLevel1::RenderTexture+0x203
wpfgfx_v0400!CD3DDeviceLevel1::TestRenderTargetFormat+0x243
wpfgfx_v0400!CD3DDeviceLevel1::CheckRenderTargetFormat+0x5b
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwTextureRenderTarget::Create+0x1e
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwSurfaceRenderTarget::CreateRenderTargetBitmap+0x73
wpfgfx_v0400!CBrushIntermediateRealizer::CreateSurfaceAndContext+0x5f
wpfgfx_v0400!CDeviceAlignedIntermediateRealizer::Realize+0x1bd
wpfgfx_v0400!CTileBrushUtils::CreateTileBrushIntermediate+0x4e
wpfgfx_v0400!CTileBrushUtils::GetIntermediateBaseTile+0x6e
wpfgfx_v0400!CMilTileBrushDuce::GetBrushRealizationInternal+0x42d
wpfgfx_v0400!CMilBrushDuce::GetBrushRealizationNoRef+0x2d
wpfgfx_v0400!CBrushResourceRealizer::EnsureRealization+0x73
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwSurfaceRenderTarget::DrawPathInternal+0xb2
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwSurfaceRenderTarget::DrawPath+0x25
wpfgfx_v0400!CHwDisplayRenderTarget::DrawPath+0x29
wpfgfx_v0400!CMetaRenderTarget::DrawPath+0xff
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::FillOrStrokeShape+0x9c
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::DrawShape+0x126
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::DrawRoundedRectangle+0x126
wpfgfx_v0400!CMilSlaveRenderData::Draw+0x1d8
wpfgfx_v0400!CMilVisual::RenderContent+0x26
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::PreSubgraph+0x6d9
wpfgfx_v0400!CGraphIterator::Walk+0x37
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::DrawVisualTree+0x230
wpfgfx_v0400!CDrawingContext::Render+0x37f
wpfgfx_v0400!CSlaveHWndRenderTarget::Render+0x1a0
wpfgfx_v0400!CRenderTargetManager::Render+0x34
wpfgfx_v0400!CComposition::Render+0x1f
wpfgfx_v0400!CComposition::ProcessComposition+0x12c
wpfgfx_v0400!CComposition::Compose+0x3e
wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::RenderPartition+0x1b
wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::Run+0x48
wpfgfx_v0400!CPartitionThread::ThreadMain+0x1c
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b


FAILURE_SYMBOL_NAME:  igdumdim32.dll!OpenAdapter

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:software_nx_fault_sehop_null_c0000005_igdumdim32.dll!openadapter


    Loaded symbol image file: igdumdim32.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\igdumdim32.dll
    Image name: igdumdim32.dll
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Mon Jun 24 17:46:07 2013 (51C869BF)
    CheckSum:         00000000
    ImageSize:        0078D000
    File version:     9.18.10.3220
    Product version:  9.18.10.3220
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          40004 NT Win32
    File type:        2.8 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Intel Corporation
    ProductName:      Intel HD Graphics Drivers for Windows 8(R)
    InternalName:     igdumdim32.dll
    OriginalFilename: igdumdim32.dll
    ProductVersion:   9.18.10.3220
    FileVersion:      9.18.10.3220
    FileDescription:  User Mode Driver for Intel(R) Graphics Technology
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Intel Corporation.
```

Your driver is a bit old. [Go to Intel.com, download the latest driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD%20Graphics) and install it.

Comment: This was genius. It helped! Thank you!

Comment: nice to hear this. Do other installers like Windows SDK now work?

Comment: Yes, SDK and VS Community installers work fine now :)