# Visual Studio 2012 & 2013 crashing at startup

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, crash

Today my VS2013 started crashing. The crash happens after 20 seconds or so. It loads up and I can interact with the application, but it crashes every time regardless of whether I click/type or leave the entire computer alone.

Tried `/safemode` and that crashes too.

Tried `/resetsettings` and `/setup`, but that didn't help.

Tried debugging the issue using VS2012, but then learned that *that* IDE crashes as well.

Uninstalled Git Extensions (commonly cited for causing startup crashes) but that hasn't helped.

Rebooted.

Deleted `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` and `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VSCommon`. No dice.

Tried starting VS with and without a solution open.

The event log contains [this error](http://pastebin.com/h0EgCuZT) and [this info message](http://pastebin.com/sWybYY2M). This is the [WER log file](http://pastebin.com/nYntiyGw), though I cannot construe anything useful from it myself.

Does anyone know how I might go about getting a working IDE again?

Comment: Hmya, a video device driver, what can possibly go wrong?  Fix your machine.

Comment: I'm trying to fix it and would appreciate help. How did you determine it is a video driver? Why on earth should that crash only VS and no other application on the PC?

Comment: Just google "igdumd32.dll".  Not a DLL that should unload while a DirectX program like VS is using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NsAppName=devenv.exe
Sig[3].Value=igdumd32.dll_unloaded
```

`igdumd32.dll` is the Intel HD driver. We just had a [similar issue some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921425/1466046).

[Go to Intel.com, download the latest driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=HD%20Graphics) and install it.

Comment: Cheers, I'll try this out tonight when I get home. Perhaps Windows Update caused it to start failing, as I haven't knowingly changed anything on the PC recently.

Comment: Tried this. Unfortunately it didn't help. My machine was already on the latest version, though I did a reinstall anyway and it still crashes. I'm wondering if there's a hardware fault. If you've any other ideas I'd be happy to hear them. Thanks either way.

Comment: Haha, ok so actually I have hybrid graphics on this laptop. The _other_ adapter is an NVidia GeForce GT-540M. Somehow, updating the driver for that display adapter seems to have resolved the problem. Go figure. I'll award the answer to you for your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Late but could be useful to someone in future:

I had the same issue recently with VS 2010 64 bit. 
My OS is Windows 8.1 64-bit.
The problem arises because of some compatibility issue between the Intel graphics driver and WPF. I solved the issue by following the workaround from here, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2894215/you-experience-performance-issues--product-crashes--or-rendering-issue